# Unable to locate element (Selenium, Sharepoint2010)

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, selenium-webdriver-c#, sharepoint

I'm new in QA.
I'm using VisualStudio 2017 + Selenium WebDriver.
I'm Trying `driver.FindElementById` in Sharepoint 2010 web page.

It is part of the **DOM**:

```html
<div id="ctl00_MSO_ContentDiv">
<a name="mainContent"></a>
<div style="padding: 20px">
    <h2>
        <span id="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_LabelCourseTitle">***</span>
    </h2>
    <h3>            
        <span id="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_LabelClassTitle">***</span>
    </h3>
    <div id="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_PanelResult">
        <h3>
            <span id="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_LabelStatus">***</span>
        </h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm try two times:

1 - it is working!

```c#
Thread.Sleep(5000);
driver.FindElementById("ctl00_MSO_ContentDiv");
```

2 - Error: `OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_LabelCourseTitle"}`

```c#
Thread.Sleep(5000);
driver.FindElementById("ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_LabelCourseTitle");
```

I don't understand, why selenium can't find child elements. All parents of "ctl00_MSO_ContentDiv" can be found. All childs can't be found. Please help.

> Update: I can stil find `<a name="mainContent"></a>`. But every thing bellow I can't find by selenium.
>   Update: Chrome dev tools search elements by XPath normally.

Comment: Can you check css that is applied to your element that cannot be found?

Comment: @AlexeyR. looks like nothing criminal. font-size, font-weight, font-family, color, it is all.

Comment: Can you find the elements in dev tools?

Comment: @MateMrše yes, by //*[@id="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_LabelStatus"] or contains(text()...

Comment: Is the element in the page but not visible initially perhaps until you click on that area

Comment: Voting to close this question as unclear what you asking, because it does not contain enough information to reproduce it. Nor would it be easy to set up a SharePoint 2010 in 2019. I also question its relevance to other visitors.

Answer (score 0):

Try this below xpath for locating the child element

```
//h2/following::span[@id="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_LabelCourseTitle"];
```

This xpath will search for the child elements.

Comment: //h2/following::span[@id="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_LabelCourseTitle"] - I try this in xpath validator with my DOM - doesn't work. And I think it will not wok becouse I try in selenium find just "h3" `driver.FindElementByXPath("//h3");` and it is faild (

Comment: if you want to find just h3 then find by using tagname driver.findElement(By.tagName("h3")); This will work

Comment: The problem is that I can not get any of the items below `<div id="ctl00_MSO_ContentDiv">` in my Sharepoint. In any way. `driver.FindElementByTagName("h3");` doesn't work.

Comment: Is there any texts present in span tag?

Comment: Yes, i replace it by ***

Comment: Then try //span[contains(text(), 'Your text')]. Replace your text in the site and try. This will work.

Comment: Sorry - not working. All that you advised is true, but -  I allready try everething: text, id, tag.  It's something wrong with sharepoint page. Litle ubdate: I can find all thet upper then `<div style="padding: 20px">`.

Comment: Sorry I dont know why it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Try with the below xpaths:

```
//div[@id='ctl00_MSO_ContentDiv']//div[@style]/h2/span[@id='ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_LabelCourseTitle']

//div[@id='ctl00_MSO_ContentDiv']/child::div[@style]/h2/span[@id='ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_LabelCourseTitle']

//div[@id='ctl00_MSO_ContentDiv']/child::div[@style]//div[@id='ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_PanelResult']/h3/span[@id='ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_LabelStatus']
```

Comment: ( Unable to locate element. With chrome devtools this xpath works fine.